# Runtime generated self signed client certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos, security

I need generate self signed client identity certificate `SecIdentityRef` on a run time using Objective C (Swift code I will convert).
This is needed to do some HTTP tunneling.

Basically application generates client identity without user interaction and  this certificate should be valid for short period (about 8 hours).

I was trying find some instruction, but so far I'm finding only topics about self signed server certificates or about using client certificate generated manually.

Comment: Are you talking about SSL Client Identity Certificates? Is the application sandboxed?

Comment: Start with adding one of the OpenSSL iOS projects to your app. You likely need to start disclosing that your app uses cryptography if you don't do that already.

Comment: I'm takin about `SecIdentityRef` and `SecCertificateRef`. My product is a library so do not have a warranty that application is sandboxed.